Pass array of unknown size to function
I want to pass an array which can have different sizes to a function. I am on an embedded system with limited capacities. I thought about the following ways of implementing it:

I don't want to use templates, because the function is called with multiple different array sizes. Every call would create a new set of this function, which would unnecessarily
blow up my project.
Using a simple pointer + length variable seems to be inelegant and unsafe. Also I couldn't nicely iterate over such a construct.
Chained lists seems to be well overcomplicated for this problem.
I don't want to use vectors, because they can not be stored statically. So maybe there could be a time, when not enough heap is available for my vector. The firmware needs to be as reliable as possible.

Is there a way of accomplishing this? Are my thoughts about the systems reliability too cautious?

Edit

Span would be a nice possibility in my opinion. But, In my case I don't have C++20 support.
Wrapper function for the template as @Some programmer dude suggested would also be an option! An advantage against a "normal" template function would be, that the function itself can still be in the source and doesn't need to be in the header file.


I think you've eliminated all the viable and preferralbe options.

C++20 allows skipping the size of the array when the array is passed by reference or pointer. int a[3]{};int b[4]{};void func(int (&ref)[]){ref[0] = 4;}int main(){func(a);func(b);} is valid C++. See demo

Do you have C++20 support? If so, ranges would be a straight upgrade over begin+length (or begin+end which may be more convenient at C++17 and lower).

std::span maybe?

You could still use a template function as a wrapper to call the real function with the size as an argument (or convert it to a vector and pass that). Yes, you will get multiple instances of the function, but it would be inlined and not really be in the way or enlarge your program (if that's your worry).

And please [edit] your question to tell us why you have these (seemingly) arbitrary limitations What is your actual task or assignment? What are the actual limitations (and requirements) of that task or assignment?

You can use option 2 with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span

I'd also go for an std::span or similar. However I also think you're being too cautious. Unless you're copying an array with thousands or millions of integers or large objects, I don't see how memory would be that much of a limitation; even on an embedded system. I get the point of saving memory, but even on safety-relevant systems I've worked on, memory never was quite this scarce.

"vectors, because they can not be stored statically"? Not so. You can have whatever allocator you like with std::vector.

@user12002570 But how do I get the size of this array with this approach?

@peter We can't. We'll need to pass the size separately.

@Someprogrammerdude Can you specify your question? I already wrote in the question, where these limitations come from. I am programming an interface on a STM32. Yes, it to have a lot of memory, but I don't want to waste this memory, by spaming template functions. An unsightly side note of templates in classes is, they need to be put in the header file. Pointer+Length -> you can not iterate nicely, prone to mistakes during call, every call gets an "unnecessary" extra argument. Chained lists would be a way, but I thought of easier solutions. Vectors...

@Caleth Vectors itself are on the stack, thats true, but the content will always be on the heap. So please explain me, how do I store the data of a vector on the stack?

@user12002570 Which would be exactly my given solution 2? Where is the advantage of using the int array reference to a simple pointer?

@peter as a sketch: template<typename T, std::size_t N> struct stack_allocator { alignas(T) std::byte data[N * sizeof(T)]; using value_type = T; void* allocate(std::size_t n) { if (n > N) throw std::bad_alloc; return data; } void deallocate(void*, std::size_t){} };

@Caleth Yeah of course, I can create a new stack vector type. I thought of using the C++ std::vector...

A span is a pointer and a length wrapped in a class that provides all the range members. You can take the declaration of std::span from C++20, and fill out the implementation, and that's compatible with C++98. Just name it something like my::span

@Caleth There's no advantage except that you can't pass a null pointer.

@peter no, that's a allocator that can be used with std::vector. You might alias that e.g. template <typename T> using stack_vector = std::vector<T, stack_allocator<T, 1000>>;, but it is an instantiation of std::vector

Most C++ algorithms operate on a [begin, end) pair. In case of a continuous array one uses pointers to the first element and behind the last, which allows for efficient iteration:
float data[SZ];
my_function(data, data+SZ);
//...

void my_function(float* begin, float* end){
  for(float* cur = begin; cur != end; ++cur){
    //do something with *cur
  }
}


Using a simple pointer + length variable seems to be inelegant and unsafe.

In this case, safety is a concern but not more than any other code where you address an array directly (indices of a vector may go out of bounds as well, linked list may lead to dereferencing a null pointer, etc).
C++20 provides std::span, a syntax sugar for this approach:
float data[SZ];
std::span<float> better_data(data);
my_function(better_data); //you can simply call my_function(data) 
                          //for implicit span construction
//...

void my_function(std::span<float> seq){
  for(float& val : seq){
    //do something with val
  }
}

(Notice that std::span can store static information about an array size but it would run counter to your desire to have one function for all array sizes.)

You don't need an intermediate span, you can pass data directly to my_function.

True, but I wanted to show span creation explicitly. Added a comment.

The use of std::begin() and std::end() (or rather using std::begin, std::end; f(begin(array), end(array)); is a big plus for code genericity.

One could also add a function template for the first version for convenience. Demo. That won't generate any extra code bloat in optimized builds.

begin/end-parameter could be a solution, but they are still prone to errors during function call. Calling a function with just the array/span/vector/etc. is much safer, than needing two parameters. So maybe this in combination with a template class, which wraps the array-call to a call with begin/end-pointer.

Span is indeed a nice solution, If I would have C++20 :(

@peter to get the basic functionality of std::span isnt that complicated. you need a pointer and the size, begin and end, but not much more. As the answer states, its merely syntactic sugar, its a vocabulary type with rather straighforward implementation
